# How to create form that contain data from 2 tables and save data to one table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, datasheet

i have 2 tables:

```
Employee:
    ID
    SalaryPerDay
    Name (unique)
    .....
    .....

Schedule:
    ID
    EmployeeID
    Date
    Attending  (boolean)
    loan
    discount
    overTimeHours
```

and a query

```
EmployeeNameQuery: that return all employees names
```

i create a datasheet contains

```
column 1: employees names (EmployeeNameQuery)
column 2: Date (Schedule)
column 3: Attening (Schedule)
column 1: OverTimeHours (Schedule)
column 4: Loan (Schedule)
column 5: Discount (Schedule)
```

this data sheet display rows as employees names count

**Questions:**

1- Decimal number display as (280) how can i display them as (280.00) i can insert decimal number but i display values with .00 without .00

2- How to create form that contain data from 2 tables and save data to one table,

when i fill all datasheet with attending i want to submit these information to Schedule Table with each field with related one in the table and insert EmployeeID of selected employeeName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regard to both one and two, it seems that you have not bound your form to a table or query.  Datasheets and continuous forms only work properly if all the data-entry controls are bound to fields. It is nearly always best to use a continuous form rather than a datasheet. If you are not familiar with form design, it is nearly always best to use the wizards, because they will set up the form with all the bindings in place.

For currency, choose the currency data type, not decimal - this is important for more than display. In addition, fields have a format property that can be set in table design.

I suggest you do some reading if you intend to continue to work in Access. You will find lists of books here on Stackoverflow - *The Access Cookbook* Getz, Litwin and Baron is often recommended.

Comment: i bound your form to a  query for employee name and to a table schedule for other fields. and i still have the same question. if you have a link for a book please post it here

Comment: Did you use the wizards to do this? If not, there is likely to be a mistake unless you are familiar with forms design. You must search google and stackoverflow for books, because you must decide how much you know and how much you want to know. You can also look at the Northwind sample database (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/northwind-2007-TC001228997.aspx) for ideas. The code is not very good, but the ideas are useful jumping off points.

Comment: i use wizards, and i still have the same problem